Cannot get psycopg2 to use in python script
I am trying to use the psycopg2 package in my python script, but I can't seem to load it.
I ran this pip install psycopg2-binary.

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2-binary in /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (2.7.5)

But when I try to import the module like import psycopg2, I get this import error:
File "/home/adm_bbyers6/rrd_get/scripts/postgres_crud.py", line 4, in <module>
import psycopg2
ImportError: No module named psycopg2

When I try to install without the binary suffix (pip install psycopg2), it fails also.
The command run below also does not work:
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.9.8 (dt dec pq3 ext) -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -DPG_VERSION_NUM=90224 -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/pgsql/server -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:28:0:
    ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
                        ^


what version of python are you trying to use?

3.6 is my version

then I would try to install it via pip3 pip3 install pyscopg-binary and run it via python3 python3 <binary>.

also, please post the output of which python and which pip

i believe I just found the problem that I have been working on all day.   I was calling this from a bash script and I did not use Python3.   I was looking in sys of 2.7.

so the python3  for the pip loading?

here, I'll post what is (hopefully) a solution as an answer

Try this.

Install the module

pip3 install pyscopg2-binary


Create a python file named test.py and enter these contents in it:

import pyscopg2
print("It works!")


Run it like this:

python3 test.py

It is basically what I think you did, except I used the python3 and pip3 install of pip and python. Remember, python and python3 are completely different binaries. Python is python2.
Hopefully this works for you...Happy coding!

the import name is just  psycopg2. And  import psycopg-binary is not even valid Python.

oops, okay that is my bad, very very sorry

thanks all.  i am good for now
